# ¿Cómo devolver el valor de una fecha a un input date en c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net

Hola amigos de la comunidad, quisiera que me apoyen, mi pregunta es algo básica, lo que desarrolle es devolver los valores de mi tabla al seleccionar el id y no tengo problemas con eso, excepto para la parte de fecha, la fecha es un datetime.
Este es mi código:

```
        OperacionesBL operaciones = new OperacionesBL();
        Libro libroEdit = new Libro();
        libroEdit.nIdLibro = int.Parse(ViewState["idEdit"].ToString());
        libroEdit = operaciones.ObtenerLibro(libroEdit);

        txtFechaPubli.Text = libroEdit.dLibFecPublicacion.ToString();
```

y esta es para la parte de mi html:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaPubli" CssClass="form-control" type="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar el atributo `textmode="DateTime"` dentro de tu etiqueta, quedaria asi

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFechaPubli" CssClass="form-control" textmode="DateTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Si hago eso se borra el calendario para seleccionar la fecha, pero igual gracias.
lo pude solucionar de esta manera "txtFechaPubli.Text = libroEdit.dLibFecPublicacion.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");"